Access Report pdf, when creating a text file for a hyperlink to open a folder on the server the link doesn't work
In my report I want to include a hyperlink to open the folder for each record in the report on the server where more information is stored. In the report, I have a text box where "text format" is Rich Text and "Display as Hyperlink" is set to always.
In my report query in the select statement I have the below. In the report, it displays the link correctly, displaying the hname, but when clicking on the link nothing happens. If I change the "Display as Hyperlink" field to "If hyperlink", the field does not create a link and only displays the hname text.
Is there a way to create a hyperlink with the name and not have to display the full path? The path is to a network drive and is extremely long being longer than a page's width and would not fit nicely in the pdf version of the report. Is there a way to create the hyperlink for the pdf that would open the folder?
SELECT
'<a href=file:///' & [hpath] & '\>' & [hname] & '</a>' AS hlink


Not related to the ANSI/ISO SQL language, so I removed the  tag.

Properly format hyperlink with # syntax and don't use RichText. Review http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html and https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=57292 and https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=89532. BTW, Excel builds hyperlinks with this same syntax.

Does this answer your question? How to get hyperlinks dynamically in Microsoft Access Reports?
